# What is the difference between 'x' and 'plus' symbol in the block diagram

Tags: control, control-system, closed-loop

Generally speaking, what is the difference between the 'x' and the 'plus' symbol in a closed loop block diagram?

For example, in 
[image]
(https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6983570)

, what's the difference between the 'cross' sign and the 'plus' sign?

Comment: The same as between `+` and `x` operators in math (note though that multiplication in Laplace domain is a convolution in time domain).

Answer (score 1):

The 'x' symbol you show refers to multiplication, its output is \$B\delta\$.

The '+' symbol you show refers to addition, the one on the left outputs \$P^*-P\$.

From the reference you provided, I understand this is given in time domain.

Comment: +1 but be careful, this might be in the Laplace domain so the multiplication could be convolution due to the properties of multiplication in the Laplace domain :)